# Relation between invertibility of Arnold's CAT map and its defining congruence relation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, modular-arithmetic, dynamical-systems

The Arnold's CAT (Continuous Automorphism of the Torus) is defined as $\Gamma\left((x, y)\right) = (2x + y, x + y) \mod 1$. Multiple sources (e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnold%27s_cat_map)) say that the map is invertible because the generating matrix has determinant 1 and therefore its inverse has integer entries. I understand perfectly that the generating matrix has an inverse matrix but what I have hard time with is convincing myself that the congruence $\mod 1$ does not cause any trouble with invertibility. So, could someone please walk me through this? Thank you!

Comment: The inverse map is from $(u,v)$ to $x=u-v$ and $y=v-x=2v-u$. Integer parts of $u,v$ combine again to integers, so under reduction mod 1 reduce to zero.

Comment: @LutzLehmann How about if $T$ is generated by any matrix $A$ such that $\det(A) \neq 0$. Is $T$ then invertible or is $\det(A) = \pm 1$ necessary?

Comment: $A$ needs to have integer entries and be invertible in the space of integer matrices, so $\det(A)=\pm 1$ is necessary.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Why is the integral part necessary? Is this some general property of toral automorphisms?

Comment: Yes, otherwise either $A$ or $A^{-1}$ will not map remainder classes to remainder classes, meaning the image of one remainder class could have parts in several remainder classes.